# Android emulator hangs with multiple errors

Tags: android-emulator, filenotfoundexception, freeze, zoneinfo

I built Android from source and when I execute the emulator it hangs on the android splash page.  Details below

```
JAVA_VERSION=1.6.0_35
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.4.11-1.fc16.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-16-Verne
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out

I execute the following command which produces the output below:

emulator -verbose -debug-all -logcat -v



W/dalvikvm(  553): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Llibcore/util/ZoneInfoDB;
W/dalvikvm(  553): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Ljava/util/Date;
E/Zygote  (  553): Error preloading java.util.Date.
E/Zygote  (  553): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadClasses(ZygoteInit.java:287)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:234)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:524)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  553): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:134)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:335)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:294)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.util.Date.getYear(Date.java:334)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.util.Date.<clinit>(Date.java:43)
E/Zygote  (  553):  ... 7 more
E/Zygote  (  553): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.version: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.util.ZoneInfoDB.readVersion(ZoneInfoDB.java:101)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.util.ZoneInfoDB.<clinit>(ZoneInfoDB.java:66)
E/Zygote  (  553):  ... 12 more
E/Zygote  (  553): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.version: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:118)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:150)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsBytes(IoUtils.java:115)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsByteArray(IoUtils.java:102)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.util.ZoneInfoDB.readVersion(ZoneInfoDB.java:98)
E/Zygote  (  553):  ... 13 more
E/Zygote  (  553): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
E/Zygote  (  553):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
E/Zygote  (  553):  ... 18 more
D/AndroidRuntime(  553): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a0d978)
emulator: _qemudPipe_closeFromGuest
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_INT_ENABLE 0
I/ServiceManager(   30): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/ServiceManager(   30): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   30): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(   30): service 'media.camera' died
I/Netd    (  670): Netd 1.0 starting
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 20
```

The missing file /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.version seems to be included in the datafile tzdata however this it seems that this file is not being read correctly.

Comment: i ever tried building android to run on emulator before, the same case, i had to wait for a few minutes to pass the splash screen

Comment: I let it run for 20min with no success.  I did see a new but unrelated error concerning a permission problem with /proc/cmdline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=38857&aid=388570000000&name=0001-Use-libcore-instead-of-frozen-libcore2.patch&token=XtlQt4ANj81pvAUEj6L5rW_SbI8%3A1351090221160

apply this patch will solve the problem.

Comment: After applying the patch I issued a make clean && make all -j8 in my root working directory and ran the emulator which now works.  Many thanks HChen.

Comment: could you elaborate how to apply this patch.

Comment: I used git so after running the commands above I copied the patch file and executed "git apply --apply /MY/WORKING_DIRECTORY/0001-Use-libcore-instead-of-frozen-libcore2.patch"